# jinja2, html: depend true or false a property display the html tag or not

Tags: html, python-3.x, jinja2

I would like to display an icon as the table row last cell depending of a key value True or False it should be two different icon from bootstrap. I supposed to implement it in the html with jinja2, Python 3.7 , Flask.
Thx if someone can help out with a syntax example. Honestly I don't get how to use e.g.: | safe or Markup()
I have that:

```
    for obj in array:
      if obj['episode_count_value'] >= 100:
        obj['is_long_flag'] = True
    return render_template('series_with_episodes.html',series=array)
```

the icons are fas fs class, from bootstrap source.

Comment: figured out. thanks anyway